# how to prevent any key long pressing jquery

Tags: jquery, keypress

i trying to restrict the inputs from user.like
the user should not press a key continuously..it can take maximum 4

Comment: you don't necessarily need javascript or jQuery to restrict text input length. you can just set the maxlength property of the text element to the value you want, in this case maxlength="4" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Comment: He is not trying to set a max length, just stop repeating characters more than 4 times, I think

Comment: You would need to validate the input using Regex on keydown event. Regex example : /^[a]{4}/

Comment: @Lance. as microsby said im not trying to set max length.just to stop repeating chars.Thanks

Comment: @Dino.For regex i have to use more classes right.isn't any other way?

Comment: @Nishanth: Maybe. The other option i see is to check the last 4 characters in the string and replace the next occurance of the same character with empty space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below code will help you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var flag=0;
  $("#txt").on('keydown',function(e){ 
    flag++;
    if(flag>4){                                    
       e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
  $("#txt").on('keyup',function(e){     
    flag=0;            
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt">
```

Comment: Replace `$("#txt").val($("#txt").val().substring(0,$("#txt").val().length-1));` with `e.preventDefault();` and I'd upvote this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. May be not the most elegant way to do but does work.

MarkUp :

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" onkeypress="CheckCharacters();" />
```

Script :

```
function CheckCharacters() 
{         
   var occurancesToCheck = 4;
   var chars = $("#txt1").val().substring($("#txt1").val().length - occurancesToCheck, $("#txt1").val().length);
   if (/^(.)\1+$/.test(chars) && chars.length == occurancesToCheck)
   {
     event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really quick and dirty, but here's a working example (via regex):

```
$('#tester').on('keydown', function(e) {

    // Check if the last four characters are the same...
    if(/(.)\1{3,}/.test($(this).val())) {

        // Only allow next character if it isn't the same...
        if (/(.)\1{4,}/i.test($(this).val() + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode))) {
            e.preventDefault();   
        }        
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L71echj8/

Answer (score 0):

@Nandha you can avoid using jQuery:

```
var doc = document; //stuff runs faster when objects are in vars

(function() {
    var flag=0;  
    doc.getElementById('txt').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
       flag++;
       if(flag>4) {                                    
          e.preventDefault();
       }
    });
    doc.getElementById('txt').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
       flag=0;            
    });
})();

<input type="text" id="txt" />
```